# Problems writing in array after malloc C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I'm having some problems trying to write in an array position of a struct, written by me, after assigned memory with the malloc function. I have to read some data from a file.txt (format for line: *int* *string* *char*. Those are an id for a person, a non particular string and a char that gives the "type" of the string to read and save), line per line, and save in the struct array. Unfortunately, often I have to add a data to a previous index in the struct array, but it seems that the program doesn't let me write in a previous index of the struct array. I don't know why. 
Hope I was clear enough. Thank you for your help!

Here's an example of file.txt:

```
    6         //number of lines
    3 tPar P
    2 tPar P
    3 tArr A
    1 tPar P
    1 tArr A
    2 tArr A
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define DBG printf("Ok linea %d\n", __LINE__);


typedef enum { 
    false, 
    true 
} bool;

struct file {
    char name[15];
    int n;
    struct record *rec;
};

struct record {
    int cod;
    char tPar[10];
    char tArr[10];
};


int read(struct file *f) {

    FILE *fd;
    char str[100];
    int pCod;
    char pTime[10];
    char pChar;
    bool found;
    int i = 0;
    int j;

    fd = fopen(f->name, "r");

    if(!fd) {
        printf("Errore di apertura file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(fd, "%d\n", &f->n);

    f->rec = malloc((f->n)*sizeof(struct record));

    if(f->rec == NULL) {
        printf("Errore nell'allocazione della memoria.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(str, 100, fd)) {

        sscanf(str, "%d %s %c", &pCod, pTime, &pChar);
        pChar = toupper(pChar);
        found = false;

        f->rec[i].cod = 0;                  // these 4 lines are needed just
        strcpy(f->rec[i].tPar, "xxx");      // to check if it writes in the
        strcpy(f->rec[i].tArr, "xxx");      // struct array

        for(j=0; j<i; j++) {
            if((pCod == f->rec[j].cod) && (pChar == 'P')) {
                strcpy(f->rec[j].tPar, pTime);  // doesn't copy
                found = true;                   
            }
            if((pCod == f->rec[j].cod) && (pChar == 'A')) {
                strcpy(f->rec[j].tArr, pTime);  // doesn't copy
                found = true;                   
            }
        }

        if(!found) {
            f->rec[i].cod = pCod;
            if(pChar == 'P')
                strcpy(f->rec[i].tPar, pTime);
            if(pChar == 'A')
                strcpy(f->rec[i].tArr, pTime);

        }

        if(pChar == 'P')
            printf("%d %s %c\n", f->rec[i].cod, f->rec[i].tPar, pChar);
        if(pChar == 'A')
            printf("%d %s %c\n", f->rec[i].cod, f->rec[i].tArr, pChar);

        i++;

    }

    fclose(fd);

    return 0;

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct file f;

    strcpy(f.name, argv[1]);

    read(&f);

    return 0;
}
```

Expected ouput:

```
3 tPar P
2 tPar P
3 tArr A
1 tPar P
1 tArr A
2 tArr A
```

Actual output:

```
3 tPar P
2 tPar P
0 xxx A
1 tPar P
0 xxx A
0 xxx A
```

Comment: Do not typedef `bool`. Instead `#include <stdbool.h>`!

Comment: there are several 'magic' numbers in the posted code, like 10 and 15 and 100.   Suggest #define those numbers, with meaningful names.  Then use the meaningful names in the code rather than those 'magic' numbers.

Comment: 'file', capitalized, is a reserved type in C.   It is very bad programming practice to re-define the system function names and types, even if the capitalization is different.

Comment: `strcpy(f->rec[j].tPar, pTime);` Do you want rewrite?

Comment: Why do you do i++? Should you only be doing that if (!found), it seems you may run into a segmentation fault in the for(f=0 ... for-loop. It looks like i is used to track the number of records, not the number of lines you've read.

Comment: @chux, the format is the one that my professor gave me, I can't do much for it.

Comment: If "file.txt" contains "//number of lines", then your code should change.  `fscanf(fd, "%d\n", &f->n);` ... `while(fgets(str, 100, fd)) { sscanf(str, "%d %s %c", &pCod, pTime, &pChar);` will not work .  Code should read and discard "//number of lines".  Easy way - use `fscanf(fd, "%d //number of lines ", &f->n);` (note space after "lines ")

Comment: @chux, yes, now I got what you were saying. I added that commet just to be clear for you, it isn't present in the original .txt.

Comment: IAC, check the return value from `sscanf(str, "%d %s %c", &pCod, pTime, &pChar)` and make certain it is 3.

Comment: Call your function something other than `read`, many systems have a system function of that name and it may clash.  Also there is no checking of buffer sizes for `strcpy` and no checking of return value of `scanf`-family functions so you may have buffer overflows and use of uninitialized values.

Comment: `pChar = toupper(pChar);` should be `pChar = toupper((unsigned char)pChar);`

Comment: Still using `i++;` outside of `if(!found) {` or did you put that it in there like @JustinDanielson suggests?  Code will fail until this is corrected.

Comment: @FedericoBacci Please respond to comment from @JustinDanielson. Seems your `i++` needs to be conditional on `!found` rather than unconditional.

Comment: @JustinDanielson, chux, I tried to put i++ in If(!found) and somehow works worse than before: now it doesn't print even the strings that printed before (the "tPar" or "tArr", to be clear).

Comment: @FedericoBacci You also need to move the `printf` up before the `i++`.

Comment: OK EVERYONE! IT WORKS! Sorry, @MattMcNabb, I really thought that the malloc was the problem. Thank you, guys! I appreciate your help!

Comment: It looked like you only wanted to write pTime when you found a duplicate pCod. If you move i into !found, you may need to remove the 3 lines around the "xxx" stuff so you're not overwriting your data. That looks like it was a quick fix for a segmentation fault or something that you were previously hitting.

Comment: With your current code, if you wrote a file.txt of 8 duplicate pCod values, you're going to get data of 1 pCod and then 7 records with "xxx"

Answer (score -3):

I suspect your enumerated values for bool are not compiled as 0 and 1, so that your test

```
if(!found) {
```

does not work as it appears.  (I can't really test my theory right now, though).

Comment: The problem isn't in that particular if, I checked and my bool works fine.

Comment: `enum`s are defined that the first one is `0` and subsequent ones are `1` greater than the previous (unless specific value assigned)

Comment: @Matt, Doh!  Yes, you are quite right.  I went and looked it up when I couldn't recall if it started at 1.